# Как избежать перенаправления на другой домен?

Tags: javascript, аудио, redirect, mp3

На сайте разместил ссылку на файл .mp3, но находится сам файл на другом сайте (домене). При клине на ссылку происходит перенаправление на другой домен, а не скачивание .mp3. Когда отлаживал на локальной машине, все работало нормально. Но в итоге на сайте происходит переадресация на другой сайт. Так же пробовал проигрывать .mp3 напрямую на сайте, через тег `audio`. Но опять же, на локальной машине все хорошо, а на сайте ничего из этого не получается.

Не подскажете, как обойти перенаправление, и возможность запустить .mp3 через тег `audio`?

Еще момент: если ссылку скопировать (не нажимать на нее, а правой кнопкой и копировать в браузере), то все работает как надо.

Comment: Вариант, можно отключить CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать это почти нельзя, особенно если стоит внутренний редерикт на ссылаемом домене